# Aspnet unexpected logout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, logout

I'm working in a project where we are using aspnet mvc 5 and we have some problems with a unexpected logout after 5 min of inactivity in a page.

I have this in my web.config:

```
<sessionState timeout="30"/>
<authentication mode="None"/>
```

What you think are causing this about project?

If need more information ask please.

Thanks.

PS: My AuthenticationType is ApplicationCookie

PS2: Added machine key to web.config and still logout after a couple of minutes:

```
<machineKey validationKey="string" decryptionKey="otherstring" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

PS3: Locally everything works fine.

Comment: What is the setting of your application pool recycling time? I assume you are using InProc Session Mode.

Comment: My application is hosted in a cloud service, how i can check that time ?

Comment: Just checking that the machine key went in the correct spot (inside of the system.web configuration tags)

Comment: @Hatjhie  Application Pool Idle Time-out is 5 Minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please extend your application pool timeout. It would solve the problem as from config posted, your website is using Session InProc Mode, the default one.

Once  the application  recycled, your information  stored in w3wp process would be gone.

Since you are using cloud services, you might also want to check how the load balancing works.

If they are not using sticky session, best is you change your session mode as well to StateServer or SQLMode.

Hope it helps. Let me know the result. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I tried SQLMode, because i don't have permissions to extend application pool timeout, and is fine now. In the beginning i'm facing some difficulties because i'm in a shared hosting and have limited access to the web server, so i run the script on my local DB, backup and restore it to the server DB.

Answer (score 4):

SessionState timeouts have nothing at all to do with login timeouts.  The users information for a login is stored in an encrypted cookie.  Based on what you said your Authentication Type is, you need to change the setup of your ASP Identity in the `StartUp` class.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout"),
            //Here is where you tell the system how long someone can stay logged in
            //while being inactive.
            ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),

            SlidingExpiration = true,
            CookieName = "LoginCookie"
        });
```

**Edit**

Given that you are hosting on a cloud service, you are most likely not sitting on a single server, but rather your application is deployed to multiple servers behind a load balancer which directs request to multiple machines.  When you are not guaranteed to be on a single server, you need to define the `MachineKey` in your web.config.  This key is what is used to encrypted/decrypt the `LoginCookie`.  If the `MachineKey` is not defined, IIS makes one up.  When on multiple servers, each server in that case would have its own `MachineKey`.  Since the keys are different, they cannot decrypt each others login cookies and thus, they think you are not logged in.

```
    <system.web>
        <machineKey validationKey="BigLongNumber" decryptionKey="DifferentBigLongNumber"
validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
    </system.web>
```

[Machine Key Generator](http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey)

Comment: Ok, now for some reason after a couple minutes inactive when i refresh page LoginCookie dissapear and logout user. What could cause this ?

Comment: @jony17 - it this across all browsers?

Comment: I will check. I'm testing mostly on chrome.

Comment: Yes, it happens on firefox and chrome. @Tommy

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to check if your server has the correct time on it.  The cookie is time based and if the server has the incorrect time, it may be thinking that the cookie has expired.  If you increase the ExpireTimeSpan to something crazy like 1 year, do you still get the same issue?

Comment: I already put in with 5 days and still logout. I will try something  more crazy.

Comment: I wouldn't think it would be that far off.  :)

Comment: @jony17 - Where are you deploying this application to?

Comment: It's on a cloud service, with Windows 2012 .NET framework 4.5 e SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Still the same. This is my cookies: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2hbh5g1mbefykcc/cookies.png?dl=0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62838/discussion-between-jony17-and-tommy).